# How to fix ld: framework not found vo-amrwb clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Tags: ios, xcode, voip, amr

I have to build `vo-armwb.framework` through shell script and now trying to use the same framework in my sample app but when trying to build the app I am getting framework not found error.

I tried to build .a or static library of the same code base and .a file is working perfectly fine but .framework gives me the error.

**I am getting the following error:**

> Ld Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/VoiceSampleApp.app/VoiceSampleApp
>   normal arm64
>       cd /Users/pradeepcr/Downloads/VoiceSampleApp
>       export IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=12.2
>       export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
>       /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang
>   -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker /usr/lib/swift -arch arm64 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS12.2.sdk
>   -L/Users/pradeepcr/Downloads/VoiceSampleApp/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos
>   -L/Users/pradeepcr/Downloads/VoiceSampleApp/VoiceSampleApp/AMRAudioSwift
>   -L/Users/pradeepcr/Downloads/VoiceSampleApp -F/Users/pradeepcr/Downloads/VoiceSampleApp/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos
>   -F/Users/pradeepcr/Downloads/VoiceSampleApp/VoiceSampleApp -filelist /Users/pradeepcr/Downloads/VoiceSampleApp/Build/Intermediates.noindex/VoiceSampleApp.build/Debug-iphoneos/VoiceSampleApp.build/Objects-normal/arm64/VoiceSampleApp.LinkFileList
>   -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker @executable_path/Frameworks -miphoneos-version-min=12.2 -dead_strip -Xlinker -object_path_lto -Xlinker /Users/pradeepcr/Downloads/VoiceSampleApp/Build/Intermediates.noindex/VoiceSampleApp.build/Debug-iphoneos/VoiceSampleApp.build/Objects-normal/arm64/VoiceSampleApp_lto.o
>   -Xlinker -export_dynamic -Xlinker -no_deduplicate -fobjc-arc -fobjc-link-runtime -L/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift/iphoneos
>   -Xlinker -add_ast_path -Xlinker /Users/pradeepcr/Downloads/VoiceSampleApp/Build/Intermediates.noindex/VoiceSampleApp.build/Debug-iphoneos/VoiceSampleApp.build/Objects-normal/arm64/VoiceSampleApp.swiftmodule
>   -framework vo-amrwb -framework AMRAudioSwift -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker /Users/pradeepcr/Downloads/VoiceSampleApp/Build/Intermediates.noindex/VoiceSampleApp.build/Debug-iphoneos/VoiceSampleApp.build/Objects-normal/arm64/VoiceSampleApp_dependency_info.dat
>   -o /Users/pradeepcr/Downloads/VoiceSampleApp/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/VoiceSampleApp.app/VoiceSampleApp
>
> ld: framework not found vo-amrwb clang: error: linker command failed
>   with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)